# fetching data from database using array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, mysqli, foreach

I have this code in `class.php`:

```
public function selectFrom(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT c.* , s.* FROM country c,segments s GROUP BY country") or die($this->conn->error);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And this code is in `index.php`:

```
<?php                           
require 'class.php';

$conn = new db_class();
$read = $conn->selectFrom();
while($fetch = $read->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    ?>
    <tr>                                        
        <td><?php printf($fetch['country']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I need to fetch data from country table using array and from table table segment also using an array.
Any help? I'm new to this. Thank u all

Comment: are you sure `new db_class();` really constructs an mysqli connection  object?

Answer (score 1):

fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* free result set */
$result->free();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is totally wrong:

```
SELECT c.* , s.* FROM country c,segments s GROUP BY country
```

here you are using the approach of `JOIN` but there is no JOIN condition specified in the query. And than `GROUP BY country` where `country` is your table name.

Please learn the basic concept first, and then try such complex query.